# Troubles with bootstrap modal with angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I have simple Angular Controller for my modal window

```
var ModalDialogCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.data;
};
```

And I have dynamic generated data from d3 (i can't use ng-click for this content). I set event in d3 onclick like this:

```
    .on("click", function(d, i) {
        //get some data           
        angular.element($('#modalDialog')).scope().data = data;
        $('#modalDialog').modal('show');
    })
```

Dialog shows without any data, but when i close it, data appears in it (closing animation with data in modal!). How I can update data in my dialog when it shows?!

[dialog first opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZrAu.jpg)

[dialog second opening and first hiding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd4Tm.jpg)

Also my Dialog code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span>
        <span class="modal-table-header"  data-dismiss="modal" ng-click='cancel()'>close</span>
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal"  ng-click='cancel()'><span class="icon-remove-circle icon-bold"></span></a>
    </span>
    </br> </br>
    <table style="display: list-item;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{data[0].headerName}}</th>
            <th ng-repeat="subData in data[0].subData">{{subData.category}}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in data">
            <td>{{item.header}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="subData in item.subData">{{subData.value}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `$apply` to let Angular know that the data has changed:

```
    angular.element($('#modalDialog')).scope().data = data;
    angular.element($('#modalDialog')).scope().$apply();
    $('#modalDialog').modal('show');
```

The first time you open the dialog immediately after setting the `data`, no `$digest` loop has executed and angular does not know that `scope.data` has been updated. Explicitly calling `$apply` will let angular know of the change before you show the modal dialog.

Before you open the modal the second time, however, I suspect that an `$digest` loop has been executed as a side-effect of some other action and, hence, you see the data.